# Google Maps API marker SVG rendering in Firefox/Edge but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, svg

My custom SVG with a logo on appears like a regular red dot on Chrome and I have no idea why, but it should be rendering as a logo. Mozilla Firefox 57.0 and Edge it renders perfectly as desired logo. I have cleared cache multiple time to verify and opened new incognito window for Chrome and it's not working.

File size is 4100 bytes.

Being imported in JavaScript as a Google Maps marker:

```
var rIcon = {
    url: 'static/rdot.svg',
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size 16 px
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
  };
```

Is there anything in the icon itself that Chrome might not like? I don't know much about SVG rules.

Also I notice it starts rendering properly after visiting full path of the SVG http://localhost/static/rdot.svg

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <metadata><?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c142 79.160924, 2017/07/13-01:06:39        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""/>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
                                                                                                    
<?xpacket end="w"?></metadata>
<defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #bf311a;
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-opacity: 0.7;
        stroke-width: 38px;
        opacity: 0.9;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <circle class="cls-1" cx="250" cy="250" r="210"/>
  <image x="198" y="122" width="104" height="256" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB8AAABNCAQAAAD04XdOAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QAAKqNIzIAAAAJcEhZcwAALiMAAC4jAXilP3YAAAAHdElNRQfhDB0JDDDz8kTrAAADG0lEQVRYw+2YO0wUQRjHf7P34oBDBI7jTfBBPK00xppCTUwsbNQYqey1sbC1sNFCiSRWFhoSC2MhMbG38JEYCwMBDAF8cDyO8IbzXrtrccexu7Pg7NFI4tds5r/zm/nm29nZ71thfqSTZXY3DZN55vnGZ95ibN8Q5hwxsvzdgsXrKPd5vo2PcIglBRzAxEcM6OfWllteTGCQYIWb3CgHLxCb5HhEtDwcNJLU0FsuDgI4C+CXbuVpwWdT1lh3TCPIEKeGNb80bi2DfCUAQI5GjnKKVhIIhKVfikY6GJbxCM94Y9PiPKGHaZtPeWppYdht7fWO9igXSDhUA0HMPXRCUtI8JuzAoVM98h8wpTAb6vgUSSocmq6OzzBFlbxIVdzEkPoe9rLr5DMh7AX/JSl5L3jQTSzvlfkXcG1vuLk3fHJveMoLrkuK3wsekBRPoetyE9VxIXET6niQavKOwTyErp4OUpa2jywL6vhxGkhb2hUs7uT8uot2B2zOV/KTpNtXxqCN+tK5lqWOOL2cY84SPBPBMLh93wU6mdLbnSNCAzBrO6wETVzlpdvsOpXUlRIQjRxJdKzLNGgmwSC44RppW5DkxYXRuEvGHd/NBBrNQB9PC4I6bhCkihCT9NO3JarigmqGeM17PlllVdwkR4zzHKGbAczSqNKDM6ikohh5gUGKPAIwCBAhDIxxhaGdcOtz1wnQQp7Zkpcm0MIycebdnNeIcpuB4q7LU0EP92hlpphbCGCaNh5y3W12jRiXeWUb8hhfyLNh2bSVRDjBmPsrE3G0x3hAjU3ZQONSYTYVe0HalpwI4Iw6Ps4QB2y4QaeX9GDE0TNNlKg6PuFop6mjSR1fwH7W+siRVsc3HXiOai953Xd0W1Kq4+egOi5c2tny8aLt39zmP74P8AC+7dPdO75B2q2vKv6DBULl40FC1p8OgKdKapUlafagOr7Cog3X8VhJrUqKzws+LimxvRViXV7wBPbevzlJjTo+RsaW06/Tzmk/dYQspb0GUqVcsFGStFv+L5nANT9TGJb6VKPJJcYAGd5xkRmL0kD3Hxf8zaNEFOrVAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It works for me on Chrome (63.0.3239.84): [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cfvhgsea/) (although the anchor is wrong)

Comment: There should be a logo overlayed on the top of the dot. Am I not allowed have overlapping graphics in a svg? For example I took a vector shape and combined it with a PNG and exported as a SVG in Photoshop. Take a look in Firefox 57.0

Comment: The suggestion in [this post](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/svg-css-background-image-not-showing-in-chrome/) allows me to see the logo in Chrome. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cfvhgsea/1/)

Comment: That makes it a typo in the data URI: `data:img` should be `data:image`

Comment: Working now, thank you so much for the help! Feel free to add it as a solution and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your svg `xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,` should be `xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,` (img vs. image):

```
<image x="198" y="122" width="104" height="256" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
```

should be :

```
<image x="198" y="122" width="104" height="256" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
```

[related link](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/svg-css-background-image-not-showing-in-chrome/)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cfvhgsea/1/)

[image: screenshot of map in Chrome]

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var rIcon = {
    url: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/mapIcons/SO_20180103a.svg',
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size 16 px
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: rIcon,
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
  })

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<img src="http://www.geocodezip.com/mapIcons/SO_20180103a.svg" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```